# ListView with Custom Layout including two RadioButtons

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am tryin to make a quiz app with translations. So there are two ArrayLists with Question Loaded in differnt languages.

I can show them in the List View as well. My problem is when I click on One Radiobutton I want the other Radiobutton to get selected as well.

I am using a ListView with a custom layout with 2 Radiobuttons .

This is my ArrayAdater for ListView

```
private class RBAdapterClass extends ArrayAdapter<cOptions> {

private ArrayList<cOptions> fOptions;
private ArrayList<cOptions> lOptions;
private ArrayList<Boolean> mChecked;    
private int mfSelectedPosition = -1;
private RadioButton mfSelectedRB;   
private int mlSelectedPosition = -1;
private RadioButton mlSelectedRB;


public RBAdapterClass(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<cOptions> lOpt, ArrayList<cOptions> fOpt)
{
    super(context,textViewResourceId,fOpt);     
    this.fOptions  =  new ArrayList<cOptions>();
    this.fOptions.addAll(fOpt);             
    this.lOptions =  new ArrayList<cOptions>();
    this.lOptions.addAll(lOpt);     
    mChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
}
    class ViewHolder {      
    TextView ForeignCode;
    RadioButton ForeignName;
    TextView LocalCode;
    RadioButton LocalName;
 }


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {

  final  ViewHolder holderf ;               
  Log.v("Convert View",String.valueOf(position));

  if(convertView==null){

    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.activity_activity_rb,null);

       holderf=new ViewHolder();           

       holderf.LocalCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.codeLocal);
       holderf.LocalName = (RadioButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioBLocal);        

       holderf.ForeignCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.codeForeign);        
       holderf.ForeignName =  (RadioButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioBForeign);


       convertView.setTag(holderf);



       holderf.ForeignName.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {                                                               

           public void onClick(View v) {  


             RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v ;   

             if(position != mfSelectedPosition && mfSelectedRB!=null  )
             {
                 mfSelectedRB.setChecked(false);                     
                 if(mlSelectedRB!=null)
                 {
                 mlSelectedRB.setChecked(false);
                 } 

             }

             mfSelectedPosition = position;              
             mfSelectedRB = (RadioButton)v;             



             cOptions optSelected = (cOptions) rb.getTag();                  

             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked on RadioButton: " + rb.getText() +" is " + rb.isChecked(), 
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             optSelected.setSeleted(rb.isChecked());  


             holderf.ForeignName.setChecked(rb.isChecked());                                
             holderf.LocalName.setChecked(rb.isChecked());


         }  
        });


       holderf.LocalName.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {                      

           public void onClick(View v) {  

             if(position != mlSelectedPosition && mlSelectedRB!=null)
             {
                 mlSelectedRB.setChecked(false);
                 if(mfSelectedRB!=null)
                 {
                 mfSelectedRB.setChecked(false);
                 }
             }                           
             mlSelectedPosition = position;              
             mlSelectedRB = (RadioButton)v;             
             RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v ;                  
             cOptions optSelected = (cOptions) rb.getTag();  
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
             "Clicked on RadioButton: " + rb.getText() +" is " + rb.isChecked(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             optSelected.setSeleted(rb.isChecked());
             holderf.ForeignName.setChecked(rb.isChecked());
             holderf.LocalName.setChecked(rb.isChecked());
         }  
        }); 


       } 

  else 

  {
        holderf = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
       }

       cOptions optfSelected = fOptions.get(position);

       cOptions optlSelected =  lOptions.get(position);

       if(mlSelectedPosition!=position)
       {

           holderf.ForeignCode.setText(" (" +  optfSelected.getsOptionsText() + ")");               
           holderf.ForeignName.setText(optfSelected.getsOptionsText());                        
           holderf.ForeignName.setChecked(optfSelected.getSeleted());                          
           holderf.ForeignName.setTag(optfSelected);               


           holderf.LocalCode.setText("("+optlSelected.getsOptionsText()+")");
           holderf.LocalName.setText(optlSelected.getsOptionsText());                          
           holderf.LocalName.setChecked(optlSelected.getSeleted());                        
           holderf.LocalName.setTag(optlSelected);             

       }

       else
       {

           holderf.ForeignCode.setText(" (" +  optfSelected.getsOptionsText() + ")");                                                      
           holderf.ForeignName.setText(optfSelected.getsOptionsText());           
           holderf.ForeignName.setChecked(optfSelected.getSeleted());
           holderf.ForeignName.setTag(optfSelected);



           holderf.LocalCode.setText("("+optlSelected.getsOptionsText()+")");
           holderf.LocalName.setText(optlSelected.getsOptionsText());                          
           holderf.LocalName.setChecked(optlSelected.getSeleted());                        
           holderf.LocalName.setTag(optlSelected);          


       }



    return convertView;
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I have edited the formatting of your post to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no check box in your code. Think it will be Radio button instead. I can't understand why do you want both radio buttons to be checked. Anyway, if you are setting those separately, (Not inside a **RadioGroup**), then you can make both checked at a time.

One suggession: write your onClick listeners outside the if-else block

Comment: CheckBox and Radio Buttons depending on the question. In this case its RadioButton. I am using ArrayList as you can as you can see from the code to make the list. Can you explain more.

Comment: Did your onClick events are working as you wrote?  One suggession: write your onClick listeners outside the if-else block.